# Julia : pass string to macro

Tags: julia

suppose that I have a macro that is defined as :

```
macro foomacro(ex::Expr)
    dump(ex)
    ex
end
```

Currently I would like to pass my expression as a parsed string so that I may pass a rather complicated and case dependent expression that has been obtained via string concatenation.

However, trying :

```
@foomacro 1+2+3
```

gives the expected result 6 whereas

```
@foomacro parse("1+2+3")
```

returns the parsed expression :(1+2+3) instead of actually parsing it...

As far as I understand this both macros should be receiving the same expression but this is clearly not the case.

How do I get this MWE to work ?

ps: I figured out this fix but I feel like it is very dirty and "incorrect"

```
macro foomacro(ex::Expr)
    if ex.head == :call
        #in this case the user is calling the macro via a parsed string
        dump(ex)
        return ex
    end
    dump(ex)
    ex
end
```

ps: if this is of any relevance, currently the code is running on 0.6.4 and if possible I'd rather not update to 1.0 yet since this would postpone my actual project to much...

Comment: Maybe you want to `eval(parse("1+2+3"))`?

Comment: No I tried this, it works in this case (since the macro is passed 6 and hence returns 6) but it doenst work in my non MWE where the macro actually does things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up levels.  Let's introduce an intermediate function for clarity:

```
function foomacro_impl(expr)
    dump(expr)
    expr
end

macro foomacro(expr)
    foomacro_impl(expr)
end
```

If run, the expression `@foomacro <someexpr>` will be parsed, the `<someexpr>` part passed to `foomacro_impl`, and the result treated as an expression and inserted instead of the original expression.  That means that writing `@foomacro 1+2+3` is equivalent to having written

```
let expr = :(1+2+3)
    dump(expr)
    expr
end
```

which returns

```
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((4,))
    1: Symbol +
    2: Int64 1
    3: Int64 2
    4: Int64 3
:(1 + 2 + 3)
```

an `Expr` that evaluates to 6.

On the other hand, in `@foomacro Meta.parse("1+2+3")`, the *whole* argument, `parse("1+2+3")`, is used as `expr`:

```
julia> let expr = :(Meta.parse("1+2+3"))
           dump(expr)
           expr
       end
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Expr
      head: Symbol .
      args: Array{Any}((2,))
        1: Symbol Meta
        2: QuoteNode
          value: Symbol parse
    2: String "1+2+3"
:(Meta.parse("1+2+3"))
```

So the result of the macro call is the expression `Meta.parse("1+2+3")`, which evaluates to *another* expression `:(1 + 2 + 3)`, since it is a call to `parse`.  The two forms are thus *not* receiving the same expression!

But there are ways to manually parse an expression and pass it to a macro:

1. You can do as I did, and use a separate "macro implementing function".  Then, the expression returned by `@foomacro bla` is equivalent to `foomacro_impl(Meta.parse(bla))`. (This approach, BTW, is very useful for testing, and I recommend it most of the times.)
2. You can use the macro `@eval` to construct an expression, splice into it, and evaluate it immediately:

   ```
   julia> @eval @foomacro $(Meta.parse("1+2+3"))
   Expr
     head: Symbol call
     args: Array{Any}((4,))
   1: Symbol +
       2: Int64 1
       3: Int64 2
       4: Int64 3
   6
   ```

   (Or similarly, use `eval` and manually constructed `Expr` values.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your in depth answer, however both approaches seem to fail when I try todo = "1+2+3" and then ATeval ATfoomacro $(Meta.parse(todo))

Comment: Using `foo_impl` might require an additional call to `eval` after it, since it returns only the expression the macro would construct. The other variant works for me. One thing, though, is that `Meta.parse` is required in Julia 1.0, and in older versions was just `parse` -- I don't know whether that is causing any problems...

Comment: Indeed, I should evaluate the resulting expression but this returns an error even though the expression generated by foo_impl and the macro are identical somehow the macro evaluates it differently, is this possible ?

Comment: your solution failed to work in my particular case but this most likely has to with underlying function for which I cannot provide a MWE.
The answer does however answer the question related to the MWE and i'll therefore accept it for other people running into the same problem :)

Comment: Hm. You could try debugging your issue using [`(@)macroexpand(1)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.macroexpand), to see what the call results in.

Comment: Misleading statement: "That means that writing `@foomacro 1+2+3` is equivalent to having written [...]". It is not equivalent because for the macro call, the returned expression is *evaluated*. The `let` block just returns the expression.